# Sync two input fields in 2 different jsps

Tags: html, jsp

If I have 2 input fields in a jsp and i want them to be in sync always, I know the solution. Write an onchange event for each input field and call a function. This function will sync the two fields.

Now in my situation, the two input fields are in two different jsps. And they are both included in a third jsp. Is it still possible to sync the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both jsps result in a single html page, on client side you are still dealing with a single page. Approach described in question should work there.

Answer (score 0):

Set an attribute in session, and use this value where ever you want using ,

```
session.setAttribute("userName",userName);
session.getAttribute("userName");
```